# Error message from Team Foundation Server Administration Console

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

After successfully (?) installing TFS 2010 (basic configuration), when I click Administer Security on the Application Tier page on the Team Foundation Server Administration Console to add users, I get the following error message:

> The server was unable to process request. ---> Team Foundation services are not available from the server.
> Technical information (for administrator):
> The request could not be processed because the application is not configured correctly. No service host is available for the request.

I have made the same kind of installation on another server without any problems, but I don't understand what the problem is in this server. What do I need to check?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error after following the MS instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=VS.100).aspx
I fixed the error by running the following command:
TFSConfig registerDB /SQLInstance:*servername* /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration

Comment: Nice one- I just rebuilt a TFS box and used the restore in the power tools which gave me the same error- this command fixed it!

Comment: I have used this command and it succeeded; I still have the error.